# How can I delete an ITable?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, esri-geodatabase, table

I have created an ITable but I need to be able to delete it if it already exists. How can I delete an ITable? This is the code that I have so far which checks for an existing ITable.

```
public static ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ITable CreateTable(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace2 workspace, System.String tableName, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFields fields)
    {
        // create the behavior clasid for the featureclass
        ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID uid = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UIDClass();

        if (workspace == null) return null; // valid feature workspace not passed in as an argument to the method

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)workspace; // Explicit Cast
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ITable table;


        if (workspace.get_NameExists(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriDatasetType.esriDTTable, tableName))
        {
            //DELETE ITABLE HERE
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot test this, but it looks like you need to get the table as a [`Table`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#Table.htm) object, which implements the [`IDataset`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IDataset.htm) interface that contains a [`Delete()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IDataset_Delete.htm) method.